# Serre condition $(S_n)$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

We know that a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ satisfies the $(S_n)$ condition if $$\operatorname{depth} M_p \geq \min(n,\dim M_p)$$ for every $p\in \operatorname{Spec}R$. 
It's well known that Cohen-Macaulay rings satisfy $(S_n)$ for all $n \geq 0$. Now is the following conclusion true:

> If $A$ is a quotient of a Cohen-Macaulay local ring and satisfies $(S_n)$ then the completion $\hat{A}$ also satisfies $(S_n)$?

I want to use the proposition 2.1.16 from *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*, Bruns-Herzog.

Comment: I don't see where the definition of fiber is used in your question. Also, if $A$ is not local, does $\hat{A}$ mean completion with respect to Jacobson radical of $A$?

Comment: I'm trying to provide the conditions of proposition 2.1.16 in (cohen macaulay rings by Bruns-Herzog)

Comment: What is $(A/p)_p$ in the def. of $F$ ? Shouldn't it be $F=B\otimes_A k(p)$ where $k(p) = A_p/pA_p = \text{Quot}(A/p)$ ? 

Comment: $k(p)=A_p/pA_p=(A/p)_p. (A/p)_p means (A/p)_{p/p}$.

Comment: This is an exercise in Matsumura's *Commutative ring theory*, page 185, Exercise 23.2.

Comment: Can you explain it,please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is too long for a comment, so I am writing it here. It reduces the problem to the case where $A$ can be assumed to be Cohen-Macaulay. But there is still an exercise remaining for you to do! All theorem and page numbers refer to Matsumura's *Commutative ring theory*.

Here are steps to do exercise 23.2 (p. 185). I am assuming all rings are local.

1. By Theorem 23.9 (p. 184) it suffices to show that all fibers of $A\rightarrow\hat{A}$ satisfy ($S_n$).
2. By assumption $A$ is a quotient of a Cohen-Macaulay ring, say $A=R/I$, with $R$ Cohen-Macaulay.
3. Let $\mathfrak{p}\in\mathrm{Spec}\ A$. This means $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}^\prime/I$, for some $\mathfrak{p}^\prime\in\mathrm{Spec}\ R$. The fiber of $A\rightarrow\hat{A}$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ coincides with the fiber of $R\rightarrow R^\prime$ at $\mathfrak{p}^\prime$. (This is explained at the bottom of page 184. To use the explanation given there we should also note that $\hat{R}/I\hat{R}=(R/I)^\hat{\ }=\hat{A}$. This is Theorem 8.11, p. 61.)
4. So now we are down to showing that all fibers of $R\rightarrow\hat{R}$ satisfy ($S_n$). It suffices to show that all fibers of $R\rightarrow\hat{R}$ are Cohen-Macaulay. This is Exercise 23.1, p. 185 again. Maybe you can spend some time thinking about this one.